# How to hide the VF page in Opportunity View in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

i am using one Vf page in opportunity page and and have one checkbox above the VF page as

Approverd ---------- checkbox

....................................................Visual force page..........................................

```
                                                    Data
```

.............................................................................................................................

what i did is when check box is uncheked the vf page or view that show above is hide on save button click that work perfectly.but the blank space is there in the place of   VF page .

I hope you got what I mean.

Comment: If you could share what your markup looks like and how you are hiding the vf page it would help. There are many ways to accomplish this so seeing the code will certainly help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 different opportunity page layouts. The first layout with your checkbox the second with the visualforce page. You assign the 2 page layouts to different RecordTypes. Your checkbox can trigger a workflow that is changing the record type and the pagelayout.

The next option is to use javascript to hide the section, but this is not reliable.